# How to reference a function from xml that is defined in kotlin's constructor?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-databinding

I'm trying to avoid writing extra lines  if possible

This works

```
class ViewModel(val clicked: () -> Unit){
    fun click(){
        clicked()
    }
}
```

But I would like to write it like this if possible

```
class ViewModel(val clicked: () -> Unit)
```

Xml looks like this

```
android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.click()}"
or
android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.clicked()}"
```

Writing the shorter version fails with cannot find method clicked()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that with this:

```
class ViewModel(val clicked: () -> Unit)
```

Inside your xml, you would have to refer to the `invoke` method of your lambda.

So something like this:

```
android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.clicked.invoke()}"
```

Edit: or...
can't you just use this?

```
android:onClick="@{viewModel.clicked}"
```

passing your lambda directly?

Comment: android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.clicked.invoke()}" works, thanks